# Hide specific H2 tags from page if specific radio button is checked by default or selected later

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I cannot edit the  HTML part!

**I must to hide the specific H2 tags** if radio button "input#existing-company" is checked by default or selected later.

I put CSS as commented code, because I bet CSS pure solution is not possible in this scenario.

Please be kind, I'm not familiar with JavaScript and jQuery.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('input#existing-company').click(function() {
       if($(this).attr('id') == 'existing-company') {
            $('#existing-company').show();           
       }

       else {
            $('#existing-company').hide();   
       }
   });
});
</script>
```

```css
/* CSS pure solution I bet is not possible
input#existing-company:checked ~ h2 {
display: none;
}
input#existing-company:checked + h2 {
display: none;
}
input#existing-company:checked > h2 {
display: none;
}
input#existing-company:checked+label ~ h2 {
display: none;
}
input#existing-company:checked+label + h2 {
display: none;
}
input#existing-company:checked+label > h2 {
display: none;
}
*/
```

```html
<div class="one">
<div class="fieldset new-company"><input type="radio" name="company_submission" id="new-company" value="new_company" class="company-selection-radio" checked=""><label for="new-company">New Company</label></div>
<div class="fieldset existing-company"><input type="radio" name="company_submission" id="existing-company" value="existing_company" class="company-selection-radio"><label for="existing-company">Existing Company</label></div>
<h2 id="comp_desired_section">Desired section 1</h2>
<h2 id="comp_section_two">Desired section 2</h2>
<h2 id="comp_desired_three">Desired section 3</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Which `h2` tags do you want to hide?

Comment: All H2 tags at once I must to hide if that radio button is checked!

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether the radio button is checked with the [`:checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked) pseudo class.

```js
$('#existing-company').on('change', checkInput)
function checkInput(){
  if($('#existing-company').is(':checked')) $('h2').hide()
}
checkInput() //if it is checked by default
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one">
<div class="fieldset new-company"><input type="radio" name="company_submission" id="new-company" value="new_company" class="company-selection-radio" checked=""><label for="new-company">New Company</label></div>
<div class="fieldset existing-company"><input type="radio" name="company_submission" id="existing-company" value="existing_company" class="company-selection-radio"><label for="existing-company">Existing Company</label></div>
<h2 id="comp_desired_section">Desired section 1</h2>
<h2 id="comp_section_two">Desired section 2</h2>
<h2 id="comp_desired_three">Desired section 3</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code running here on Stack Overflow! I add your code in a WordPress page, I've embraced him between "<script type="text/javascript">YOUR CODE"</script> and not works. Code is add correctly, via a snippet. What could be wrong?

Comment: @Marius Did you import jQuery? Where did you place your `script` tag?

Comment: This is the entire code that I've add via a snippet: https://ibb.co/Wp1fxPM

Comment: @Marius Wrap the code in a document ready event. E.g, `$(document).ready(function(){ <-- code here --> })`. The element may not have been loaded when the code executed.

Comment: After I wrap the code it works on my WordPress page, BUT if it is selected again the button radio "New Company", the H2 tags continue to remain hidden. Even here on Stack Overflow at your code if it is clicked again the radio button "New company", the H2 tags continue to remain hidden. Can you please adapt the code to display H2 tags when the radio button "New company" is clicked.